# UITableView estimatedRowheight Dynamic Type

Tags: ios, uitableview, row-height

I'm using self-sizing table view cells to support Dynamic Type.

When the user sets their font size to normal, the row height is 44. But, when the user adjusts their font to be smaller or larger, the row height decreases or increases, respectively.

So, what should I set the `estimatedRowHeight` to, since `rowHeight` changes depending on the user's Dynamic Type settings?

Comment: It's just an estimate to speed up calculations. You don't need to be precise. Set it to 44 and you'll be fine

Comment: I know I don't need to be precise, as it's just an estimate, but I'd still like to be accurate. [Auto Layout Guide: Working with Self-Sizing Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) says, "try to make the estimated row height as accurate as possible. The system calculates items such as the scroll bar heights based on these estimates. The more accurate the estimates, the more seamless the user experience becomes."

Answer (score 0):

When the default Dynamic Type is chosen the .body pointSize is 17.0, so I use this calculation

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = [yourEstimateForDefaultSize] / 17.0 * UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).pointSize
```

For the default Dynamic Type size this estimate is accurate. For other sizes it loses accuracy, but its an improvement

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to estimate the height dynamically using a delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return topOffset + bottomOffset + fontSize * countOfLines
}
```